# In Swift, how does one manipulate an object inside a typealias?

Tags: swift, type-alias

I have a typealias I would like to manipulate one of the objects in it after receiving it as s one completion handler and before sending it to another.  So

```
typealias GalleryResponse = (gallery: MLGallery?, error: NSError?) -> ()
```

and the function i’d like to intervene on the typealias:

```
func getGalleryForDiscover(onCompletion: galleryResponse) {

    let endpointURL = kGalleryURL + kMetaDataFilter + kLimitURL20

    /// Would like to do something here with the MLGallery object in the galleryResponse closure.   

    makeRequestToCurbsAt(endpointURL, completionHandler: onCompletion)
}
```

How do I get to that `MLGallery` object - manipulate it - and then send it on?

Comment: Your question is really vague.
Try to provide more details regarding MLGallery

Comment: typealias means exactly type alias. in you case galeryResponse is the alias for function with signature (gallery: MLGallery?, error: NSError?) -> (). no less, no more ....

Comment: You manipulate the gallery in the galleryResponse in the galleryResponse closure that you are passing in to your getGalleryForDiscover function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide `makeRequestToCurbsAt` with its own completion handler, you then 
manipulate the `MLGallary` instance passed to that handler, and then pass it on to the original handler.  Like such:

```
func getGalleryForDiscover(onCompletion: galleryResponse) {
    let endpointURL = kGalleryURL + kMetaDataFilter + kLimitURL20

    makeRequestToCurbsAt(endpointURL, completionHandler: {
        (gallery: MLGallery?, error: NSError?) in
      // do something with gallery

      // invoke the original
      onCompletion (gallery: gallery, error: error)
    })
}
```

Note: Really, really, your typealias identifier should be capitalized as `GalleryResponse`.

Comment: In scrubbing the code of the vendor providing that gallery, I forgot to capitalize the G.

Comment: Thank you @GoZoner - exactly what I was seeking.